# MPI matrix multification compile err: undeclared with code

Tags: matrix, mpi

I coded a mpi matrix multification program, which use `scanf("%d", &size)`, designate matrix size, then I defined `int matrix[size*size]`, but when I complied it, it reported that matrix is undeclared. Please tell me why, or what my problem is!

According Ed's suggestion, I changed the matrix definition to if(myid == 0) block, but got the same err! Now I post my code, please help me find out where I made mistakes! thank you!

```
int size;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

int myid, numprocs; 
int *p; 
MPI_Status status; 
int i,j,k; 
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid); 
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs); 
if(myid == 0)
 {       
  scanf("%d", &size); 
  int matrix1[size*size];
  int matrix2[size*size]; 
  int matrix3[size*size];
  int section = size/numprocs; 
  int tail = size % numprocs; 
  srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
  for( i=0; i<size; i++) 
     for( j=0; j<size; j++)
        { 
            matrix1[i*size+j]=rand()%9;
            matrix3[i*size+j]= 0; 
            matrix2[i*size+j]=rand()%9; 
         }            
      printf("Matrix1 is: \n"); 
      for( i=0; i<size; i++) 
         {            
             for( j=0; j<size; j++)
              {
                  printf("%3d", matrix1[i*size+j]); 
              }       
             printf("\n");   
         }         
       printf("\n");   
       printf("Matrix2 is: \n");
```

Comment: how about reformatting your code?

Comment: hehe, I tried, but the layout seems not to work!
BTW, I have sovled the problem! I tried a #define MAX_SIZE 500, then I just use part of the array ^u^

Answer (score 0):

Reformatted code would be nice...

One problem is that you haven't declared the size variable.  Another problem is that the [size] notation for declaring arrays is only good for sizes that are known at compile time.  You want to use `malloc()` instead.

Comment: thanks, I think scanf("%d", &size) can work at run time! I've try scanf("%d", &size);
int matrix[size];
successfully on my own computer. but on mpi environment, it sucks! that is where I comfused!

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to define a MAX_SIZE if you use dynamic memory allocation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
...
   scanf("%d", &size); 
   int *matrix1 = (int *) malloc(size*size*sizeof(int)); 
   int *matrix2 = (int *) malloc(size*size*sizeof(int)); 
   int *matrix3 = (int *) malloc(size*size*sizeof(int));
...
```